# Convert NOT IN to LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT id from patients_member where id NOT IN
(SELECT msc.member_id 
    FROM journeys_memberstagechallenge msc
    WHERE msc.challenge_id = '2ab9a76c1ad211e7a1350242ac110003'
          AND msc.completed_date IS NOT NULL);
```

I need to update this query so that it only has left joins and conditions, so that my code generator can generate it automatically.
Please help.

Comment: At this point I would be sorely tempted to switch code generator.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like following.

```
SELECT t1.id 
FROM   patients_member t1 
       LEFT JOIN journeys_memberstagechallenge t2 
              ON t2.member_id = t1.id 
                 AND t2.challenge_id = '2ab9a76c1ad211e7a1350242ac110003' 
                 AND t2.completed_date IS NOT NULL 
WHERE  t2.member_id IS NULL
```

Comment: This works, but another condition that I have in my code generator is "I can't append more conditions on JOIN". So is there a way to move those conditions in WHERE clause.

Comment: I am afraid, you can't put the condition of left join to where condition, it will give you wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

This would look like:

```
select pm.id
from patients_member pm left join
     journeys_memberstagechallenge msc
     ON msc.member_id = pm.id and
        msc.challenge_id = '2ab9a76c1ad211e7a1350242ac110003' and
        msc.completed_date is not null
where msc.member_id is null;
```

The conditions on the second table go in the `on` clause.  The `where` clause -- checking for no match -- implements the `not in` condition.